# DST conversion issue with moment add

Tags: momentjs, dst

I am trying to add hours with moment in DST timezone. Hours are added correctly, however the DST timezone is not identified.

Example: I am adding 4 hours to "Sat Oct 31 2015 20:00:00 GMT-0400" which is (Eastern Daylight Saving time). After adding 4 hours I am getting "Sun Nov 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400". Expected result is "Sun Nov 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500" as Daylight saving is ended on 1st Nov 2015.

Set your local machine timezone to (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada) while testing it.

```
var date1 = moment('2015-10-31T20:00:00-04:00').toString();
console.log(date1)
output- Sat Oct 31 2015 20:00:00 GMT-0400

var convertedDate = moment($scope.date1).add('hours',4).toString();
console.log(convertedDate)
output- Sun Nov 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/nF06r0YEjOk78F4QbtvF?p=preview
```

-Jimit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things

1. Please update your question to show your code here on StackOverflow.  You should only show the parts necessary to ask your question.
2. Looking at your code on Plunker, you should prefer to use `format` instead of `toString`, but that's not the cause of the issue.
3. Also, you are creating a string just to parse it again, which is inefficient and can sometimes lead to errors.  Though that's not the cause here either.
4. The main issue is that you are working under the assumption that DST ends in the US Eastern Time zone at midnight, when actually it ends at 2:00 AM.  The clocks will advance from `2015-11-01T01:59:59.999-04:00` to `2015-11-01T01:00:00.00-05:00` one millisecond later.

   Moment can handle this just fine.

   [image: example]

Note the part I highlighted, showing the 1:00 hour repeated with the offset changing, due to the DST fall-back.

Comment: Got that Matt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> "Currently, daylight saving time starts on the second Sunday in March
>   and ends on the first Sunday in November, with the time changes taking
>   place at 2:00 a.m. local time."
>
> [Daylight saving time in the UnitedStates.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States)

Indeed, you can see the daylight saving change between 5 and 6 hour shifts.

Comment: With all due respect, I can't understand why it's not a sufficient answer. OP was taking as granted that the time daylight saving time ends at Sun Nov 01 2015 00:00:00 while in truth, it ends at Sun Nov 01 2015 02:00:00. Stating that, answers the "[..]however the DST timezone is not identified." part of the question, right?

Comment: I was not trying to critique OP's question, I identified the part of his confusion and provided with a solution.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting it. It helped. Marked response from Matt as answer just because it helped me clarifying the cause with evidence.

Comment: Hi Sevle, and thanks for participating!  While your statement is accurate, it doesn't provide enough context.  Stating the valid time alone doesn't connect the dots for the average reader.  Remember that StackOverflow is mostly about creating a reusable resource of questions and answers for others who may have the same issue, so it pays to be more explicit.  Otherwise it's more of a comment than an answer. You may also want to read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)